# What are the advantages of using C++/CLI instead of C# for wrapping a (third party) C-library (dll)?

Tags: c#, c, dll, c++-cli, wrapper

I have a third party C-libraries which I need to use from C#. The rest of the system is written in C#, so using C++/CLI is only an option for the wrapper.

What are the advantages of using C++/CLI for wrapping C-libraries instead of C#? Is there any advantages in creating a C#-wrapper?

The libraries contains some structs, a few enums and lots of functions.

Edit: Would it be possible to use  C structs and enums in C# without wrapping them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advantage of using C++/CLI is that you can write both native code and managed code in the same assembly.

Interacting with C Libraries is easier when using C++/CLI, you can work with your libraries normally with all the  and still expose fully managed .NET interfaces or classes. But of course C++/CLI adds some complexity.

On the other hand in C#, you need to redeclare all structs and use DllImport to declare your C-Functions again in C#.

I'd say for simple interop tasks (like just some functions and few structs), using C# and PInvoke is just ok. If using a complete API that would require lots of struct redefinitions, pinning, conversions and whatever, C++/CLI is probably the better choice.

Comment: So it is basically a question of the complexity of the library. For more complex libraries use C++/CLI, but you can get away with C# with simple libraries.

Comment: @HåkonK.Olafsen Yes, essentially. Of course it also depends on what you want to do with the results. If they need lots of "C++ stuff" to handle, like memcpy, reinterpret_cast etc, it might also be a case for C++/CLI.